# AN: how to get update event from sockets?

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to understand the many features AN has developed over normal node api and by reading the code I realize that if you need to be notified of a property change with the classical update hooked to a function call it needs to be declared as normal blender property and there is no way to get update notification with sockets data? For example:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import *
from ... base_types.node import AnimationNode

class TestNode(bpy.types.Node, AnimationNode):
    bl_idname = "an_TestNode"
    bl_label = "Test node"

    def runUpdate(self, context): #this never get's called by run2 update
        print("update ", self.run1)
        #print("update ", self.run2 ) #<---- this error not sure how to get it

    def draw(self, layout):
        layout.prop(self, "run1")

    run1 = BoolProperty(name = "run1", default = False, update = runUpdate)

    def create(self):
        self.newInput("Boolean", "run2", "run2", update=self.runUpdate, value = False)

    def execute(self,run2):  
        if run2:
            print("RUN 1 ", self.run1)
            print("RUN 2 ", run2)
```

In this example the only way (I know) to get run2 value is with the main execute function and update=self.runUpdate never get called.

Also I noticed all the time blender props get hooked to events.propertyChanged / executionCodeChanged etc and/or the function calls createSockets() with @keepNodeState decorator and inside this function the sockets get declared. can someone tell me if I got it right and how is supposed to work to get notified if a value in the socket change and in general what is the correct way to take advantage of these events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A node should not react to changes of the value of a socket. What you are trying to do is not possible. You cannot create an event handler yourself that is executed when the eg the boolean input socket changes.

Also `run2` is not a property of the node. This is why `self.run2` raises an error. The final value of `run2` is passed into the execute function. It my differ from the value of the socket (when the value comes from another node via a link).

The `propertyChanged` and `executionCodeChanged` event handlers are mostly used by the Auto Execution system. When `propertyChanged` is called the tree will execute (only if *Property Changed* is activated in the Auto Execution panel).

The `executionCodeChanged` event on the other side triggers a new generation of the execution code. Furthermore the new execution code will be executed if *Tree Changed* is activated in the Auto Execution panel.

The `keepNodeState` decorator stores the current values and links to a node in the beginning of the function execution and sets them back on the newly created sockets when the real function ends. This makes it much easier to update sockets without having to care about all the details every time.

When you create/move/remove sockets the `treeChanged` event is called automatically. It does pretty much the same as `executionCodeChanged`. This is why I don't have to call `executionCodeChanged` again after I changed the sockets.

Comment: Very complete answer and architecture, this make more sense now, even  if I find strange not being able to register my own functions to the change of some value exactly in the case of propertyChanged. I guess is because I'm used to thing to programs "isolated" not that every time it has to run the whole tree